# WPF Webbrowser: Launch method in view model once webbrowser loaded/rendered event completes

Tags: wpf, mvvm, webbrowser-control

I have a MVVM WPF application which in the main window I have placed a webbrowser component. I has binded a property in view model to the HtmlText property in Webbrowser.

Now I am trying to launch a method in view model when webbrowser has loaded (rendered) its content completely. I know there is a loaded event in webbrowser but I do not know how to from the view launch the method in view model on loaded (rendered) complete.

How can I do this?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the event in the view and call the method of the view model?

```
private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
    vm.Method();
}
```